# Ansible calculate a value which should not be greater than a specific value

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm working on an Ansible task which should set the JVM heap size in a text file (Code example below)

The value for the JVM heap size is currently calculated like so - which works  fine:

- Ansible fact systems total memory in MB (`ansible_momtotal_mb`)
- divided by 1000 to get GB
- multiplied by 0.6 to only use 60% of the memory
- filtered with `| int` to get a rounded number without decimal places

My problem is: The calculated value should not be higher than 8 GB and I don't know how to set a max value to a calculation

My code:

```yaml
- name: "Set JVM heap size"
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: "/etc/path/jvm.options"
    regexp: '-Xms([0-9])g'
    replace: '-Xms{{ (ansible_memtotal_mb / 1000 * 0.6) | int }}g'
```

Does anybody has an idea on how to set a maximum value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How to set a maximum value?*

One approach could be to use an Ansible Jinja2 Templating IF ELSE construct to specify an upper limit like in the minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    ansible_memtotal_mb: 16384 # 2048, 4096, 8192, 32768

  tasks:

  - name: Show value with upper limit
    debug:
      msg: "{% if (ansible_memtotal_mb / 1000 * 0.6) | int < 8 %}{{ (ansible_memtotal_mb / 1000 * 0.6) | int }}{% else %}8{% endif %}"
```

resulting into the requested output.

To have it better readable and maintainable

```yaml
  - name: Calculate XMS without upper limit
    set_fact:
      XMS: "{{ (ansible_memtotal_mb / 1000 * 0.6) | int }}" 

  - name: Show XMS value with upper limit 
    debug:
      msg: "{% if XMS | int < 8 %}{{ XMS }}{% else %}8{% endif %}"
```

Please take note that

- to prevent to get a float value cast to int even if [`set_fact` will result into a string](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html)
- cast XMS to integer again because it was registered as string